# How to identify password protected read only file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a password protected file and need to check if it is read only.

If I use `Workbooks.Open Filename:=[filename], Password:=[password]` and the file is open read only by another user it prompts me for the password and therefore stops the macro.

If I use `GetAttr(filename)` it shows `32` (read/write) even though the file is open **read only** by another user.

I tried this but it comes back Read only as False.

```vb
Function FileIsReadOnly(filePath As String) As Boolean
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Dim fil As Scripting.File
    Set fil = fso.GetFile(filePath)
    FileIsReadOnly = fil.Attributes And ReadOnly

End Function
```

How do I test if a file is open read only, either by opening it and bypassing the password prompt, or getting the correct system attribute of Read Only?

Comment: By read-only do you mean the read-only file attribute at the file system level? Or do you mean that the Excel workbook is password protected as read-only?

Comment: Excel does not use file system attributes to indicate that the file is readonly. It's an internal representation in the file itself, so the file attributes aren't going to provide any information.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function IsPasswordProtected(ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    'Dare to try opening the file with a password that never matches.
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName, , True, , "THIS_PASSWORD_NEVER_MATCHES")
    On Error Goto 0
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        IsPasswordProtected = True
    Else
        wb.Close False
        Set wb = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

If this is ok for you , please vote for this answer.